# Java: does adding indentation or comments affect javadoc generation from Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, comments, javadoc, indentation

Let's say if I've generated a javadoc from Eclipse. Then I figured that my code is a bit messy and I wanted to add in indentations and comments to tidy it up.

Will I need to generate a new javadoc because my code is somewhat "changed" due to addition of indentation or comments? Or can I just use the old javadoc if there is no difference?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaDoc is used to document your code, you use it to describe what some part of your code does. 
If arguments passed to your function doesn't change, value returned any side effect (variable modification, exception throwing) either, you can leave it as it is.